# Найти число и перенести в другую часть строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
<p>=1= Текст1</p><p>=2= Текст2</p><p>=3= Текст3</p>
<p>=2= Текст4</p><p>=1= Текст5</p>
```

Нужно заменить на:

```
<p class="myclass1">Текст1</p><p class="myclass2">Текст2</p><p class="myclass3">Текст3</p>
<p class="myclass2">Текст4</p><p class="myclass1">Текст5</p>
```

То есть между равно предполагается идентификатор класса для легкого поиска и чтобы не путать его с другими числами в строке. Код может быть от 1 до 9. Вместо равно можно что-то другое придумать.

Возможно ли сделать такую замену с помощью replace()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p>\s*=(\d)=\s+(.+?)<\/p>
```

меняем на

```
<p class="myclass$1">$2</p>
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/WWPxyk/2)